# Check if two IP addresses are in a range

Tags: bash, shell, networking, perl

Using bash or perl on a minimal installed Linux, I am trying to validate two IP addresses if there are in a range.

I came across a bash script that works well, but the fact that it prints all the IP addresses in a range, it takes longer to complete a bigger range. I am not interested in printing all the individual IP addresses but simply to check if two given IP addresses are in a range. How can achieve my goal?

Example would be

```
"1.1.1.1 - 1.1.1.10"  is correct (This a valid range)
"1.1.2.1 - 1.1.1.10"  is incorrect (This is NOT a valid range)
```

Bash function below

```
#!/bin/bash
# convert IP to decimal
ip2dec() {
        set -- ${1//./ }     # split $1 with "." to $1 $2 $3 $4
        declare -i dec       # set integer attribute
        dec=$1*256*256*256+$2*256*256+$3*256+$4
        echo $dec
    }

# convert decimal to IP
dec2ip() {
        declare -i ip1 ip2 ip3 ip4
        ip1=$1/256/256/256
        ip2=($1-$ip1*256*256*256)/256/256
        ip3=($1-$ip1*256*256*256-$ip2*256*256)/256
        ip4=$1-$ip1*256*256*256-$ip2*256*256-$ip3*256
        echo $ip1.$ip2.$ip3.$ip4
        }

    start_ip=$(ip2dec $1)
    eend_ip=$(ip2dec $2)

    for ((i=$start_ip;i<=$end_ip;i++)); 
    do
    dec2ip $i
    done
```

Script usage:  `./script_name 1.1.1.1 1.1.1.10`

Comment: Any two addresses are in the "0.0.0.0/0" range (that's the entire address space), not really interesting, so you need to define what is a valid range in your case. The script you show is really poorly formatted, but the case you show would be caught by `ip2dec($1) > ip2dec($2)`, leading me to think that you not only lack proper understanding of IP addressing (then you would have known to define "valid range") but also that you have a poor understanding of bash, leading to the obvious question: Why are you doing this?

Comment: Since you mentioned Perl, there are actual pre-existing modules in Perl for handling of IP addresses. It might be smarter to look at those rather than implement it yourself with any tool, in particular the shell.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity, looking at the script, I think the two addresses given are the endpoints of the range. So there's a third address they want to check.  With that script, I suppose it'd be something like  `./script_name 1.1.1.1 1.1.1.10 | grep 1.1.1.7`... Though it does say "to check if _two_ given IP addresses are in a range", hmmh.

Comment: @ilkkachu: But that's not a standard range - the only range that starts at 1.1.1.1 is a /32 and that does not include 1.1.1.10 (the smallest range to include both are 1.1.1.0/28). I haven't looked at the perl modules you mention, but I would be wary of using them with a non-standard definition of range.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity, it's not a power-of-two block or prefix, and you can't use it for routing as such, but I don't know why that should matter. It's trivial  to define a range of contiguous addresses, even for non-powers of two. Here, that would just be the addresses 1.1.1.x, with 1 <= x  <= 10, but you could do the same for ranges like 1.1.1.90 - 1.1.2.100. With some typos fixed, the script above works just fine for such a range.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity, as for non-standard, well the funny thing is that even things like the RIPE database support and have ranges like that, try e.g. [`whois 86.38.98.0`](https://apps.db.ripe.net/db-web-ui/query?searchtext=86.38.98.0), which finds the range 86.38.98.0 - 86.38.127.255. `ipcalc` can decompose that into the four (power-of-two) prefixes it contains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the writing of this answer, your question mentions there are "valid" ranges of IP addresses and "NOT valid" ranges, but you haven't defined how to test for the validity of a given address range.  I guess that's not in the scope of the question.

That leaves us with how to compare an address with the lower/upper addresses in the range.  Finally, all three of these addresses are converted to decimal values.  I.e., integers.

My own bash routine to convert an IPv4 dotted-quad address string to an integer looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare ip_int=0

ip2int () {
  local addr="$1"
  local ip IFS=.

  # use IFS to split dotted quad into array of octets
  # i.e., "10.200.251.22" => ( "10" "200" "251" "22" )
  ip=( ${addr} )

  # bit shift the octets and combine into integer via bitwise-or
  ip_int=$(( ip[0] << 24 | ip[1] << 16 | ip[2] << 8 | ip[3] ))
}

# get ip address as integer in $ip_int
ip2int 10.12.13.14

# show decimal and hex values, just for confirmation purposes
printf 'decimal: %d\n'   $ip_int
printf '    hex: %08x\n' $ip_int
```

If you put your integer values for the range in `$start_ip`/`$end_ip` and the integer value for the current address in `$cur_ip`, then testing the address is within the range is fairly simple pair of comparisons:

```
[[ ${cur_ip} -ge ${start_ip} && ${cur_ip} -le ${end_ip} ]] && echo "In the address range"
```

I.e., if the current address is equal to or greater than the starting ip, and it's equal to or less than the ending ip, then it's within the range.